# Encrypting Dependent Text Files at Compile Time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building a console app that makes REST Calls to a web service.  Prior to making the REST call I have to read in a sensitive JSON file which contains my client ID and client key in order to make the call.

What options or best practices should I use to encrypt that file so that the client id and key cannot be visible by reverse engineering or seen with System Internal utilities?

Comment: Where is the JSON file?

Comment: in my solution files